# Deserialize XML in Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I have seen these questions asked before but I haven't seen an answer that solves deserializing the xml structure that I am trying to. I have come from a C# background so python is very foreign to me.

The xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <rss xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
   <channel>
    <title>blah blah</title>
    <item>
        <title>123</title>
        <description>Event Status</description>
        <a10:link href="xxx" />
        <REMITUrgentMarketMessages xmlns="xxxx">
            <UMM xmlns="">
                <messageId>A000000/messageId>
                <event>
                    <eventStatus>Inactive</eventStatus>
                    <eventType>Storage </eventType>
                    <eventStart>2019-10-06T09:43:00+01:00</eventStart>
                    <eventStop>2019-10-09T13:20:00+01:00</eventStop>
                </event>
                <unavailabilityType>Unplanned</unavailabilityType>
                <publicationDateTime>2019-10-09T13:21:19+01:00</publicationDateTime>
                <capacity>
                    <unitMeasure>TWh</unitMeasure>
                    <unavailableCapacity>1.03227</unavailableCapacity>
                    <availableCapacity>2.1317295</availableCapacity>
                    <technicalCapacity>3.1639995</technicalCapacity>
                </capacity>
                <unavailabilityReason>Failure</unavailabilityReason>
                <remarks> </remarks>
                <balancingZone>21YGB</balancingZone>
                <affectedAsset>
                    <name xmlns="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITUMMCommonSchema_V1.xsd">xxxx</name>
                    <eic xmlns="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITUMMCommonSchema_V1.xsd">xxxx</eic>
                </affectedAsset>
                <marketParticipant>
                    <name xmlns="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITUMMCommonSchema_V1.xsd">vvvvv</name>
                    <ace xmlns="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITUMMCommonSchema_V1.xsd">vvvvvv</ace>
                </marketParticipant>
            </UMM>
        </REMITUrgentMarketMessages>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>458</title>
        <description>Event Status</description>
        <a10:link href="xxxxx" />
        <REMITUrgentMarketMessages xmlns="xxxxxx">
            <UMM xmlns="">
                <messageId>A000001</messageId>
                <event>
                    <eventStatus>Dismissed</eventStatus>
                    <eventType>Storage</eventType>
                    <eventStart>2019-10-06T09:43:00+01:00</eventStart>
                    <eventStop>2019-10-10T18:00:00+01:00</eventStop>
                </event>
                <unavailabilityType>Unplanned</unavailabilityType>
                <publicationDateTime>2019-10-06T09:45:22+01:00</publicationDateTime>
                <capacity>
                    <unitMeasure>TWh</unitMeasure>
                    <unavailableCapacity>1.03227</unavailableCapacity>
                    <availableCapacity>2.1317295</availableCapacity>
                    <technicalCapacity>3.1639995</technicalCapacity>
                </capacity>
                <unavailabilityReason>Failure</unavailabilityReason>
                <remarks> </remarks>
                <balancingZone>21YGB</balancingZone>
                <affectedAsset>
                    <name xmlns="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITUMMCommonSchema_V1.xsd">sssss</name>
                    <eic xmlns="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITUMMCommonSchema_V1.xsd">sssss</eic>
                </affectedAsset>
                <marketParticipant>
                    <name xmlns="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITUMMCommonSchema_V1.xsd">uguu</name>
                    <ace xmlns="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITUMMCommonSchema_V1.xsd">vvvvv</ace>
                </marketParticipant>
            </UMM>
        </REMITUrgentMarketMessages>
    </item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

I have tried using xml.etree.ElementTree  to load in the tree and for loop over the nodes however I don't see this as an elegant solution and think using BeautifulSoup like the code below is better

```
    a = BeautifulSoup(self.text, "xml")
    items = a.find_all('item')
    for i in range(0, len(items)):
        messageId = items[i].find('messageId').get_text()
        eventStatus = items[i].find('eventStatus').get_text()
        eventType = items[i].find('eventType').get_text()
        eventStart = items[i].find('eventStart').get_text()
        eventStop = items[i].find('eventStop').get_text()
        unavailabilityType = items[i].find('unavailabilityType').get_text()
        publicationDateTime = items[i].find('publicationDateTime').get_text()
        unitMeasure = items[i].find('unitMeasure').get_text()
        unavailableCapacity = items[i].find('unavailableCapacity').get_text()
        availableCapacity = items[i].find('availableCapacity').get_text()
        technicalCapacity = items[i].find('technicalCapacity').get_text()
        unavailabilityReason = items[i].find('unavailabilityReason').get_text()
        remarks = items[i].find('remarks').get_text()
        balancingZone = items[i].find('balancingZone').get_text()
        assetName = items[i].find('name').get_text()
        assetEic = items[i].find('eic').get_text()
        marketParticipantName = items[i].find('marketParticipant').find('name').get_text()
        marketParticipantAce = items[i].find('ace').get_text()
```

Ultimately I'm trying to find out if a .net equivalent of xml deserializer exists in python which will convert the xml string into a class